# Spectral representation intuitive explanation

Tags: functional-analysis, intuition, spectral-theory, compact-operators, adjoint-operators

I am following a course in functional analysis and in the lectures we encountered the following theorem:

> Theorem: Let H be a Hilbert space and $T:H\to H$ a self-adjoint and compact operator. Then: $T = \sum_{\lambda\in\sigma(T)}\lambda\pi_\lambda$

Here $\pi_\lambda$ is the orhtogonal projection on the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$. We also assume that $T$ is always bounded.

My question now is how can I intuitively understand this better? Does this theorem have any nice corollaries? Can someone maybe give an example for infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces and a operator satisfying the conditions?

Thanks!

Comment: You can relate this to the finite-dimensional case. The spectrum consists only of eigenvalues, and you can find a basis of orthonormal eigenvectors. The spectral theorem is merely a generalization.

Comment: Okey I see, can u give an example that is a bit trivial so I can work on it? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your background, but I like to think about it in terms of a spectral problem. Suppose you are interested in all pairs $(\lambda, u)$ satisfying $Lu = \lambda u$ together with some boundary conditions, where $L$ is a second-order linear differential operator. Such problem arises naturally when you are studying a mechanical system and you are looking for time-harmonic solutions of the linearized problem. The spectral theorem gives you conditions guaranteeing that $\lambda$ are just eigenvalues, i.e., you don't have to worry about residual or continuous spectrum.

The classical example is the Laplacian $L = -\Delta$ with Dirichlet boundary condition acting on $H = L^2$. Keep in mind that differential operators are not bounded operators (which means they can't be compact), so you would look at the inverse of $L$ instead.

Comment: I am a bachelor student in mathematics. :) Thank u for ur explanation.

Comment: @Main From a mathematical perspective, the result tells us that the result in the finite-dimensional setting carries over to the infinite-dimensional setting provided the conditions are met (bounded self-adjoint). The moral here is that what we know is true in the finite-dimensional setting might not be true in the infinite-dimensional setting, but when it does, then life is good (: Another example to have in mind is that the closed unit ball is compact in $X$ if and only if $X$ is a finite-dimensional normed space.

Comment: Thank u @Chee Han! Can u maybe also help me with my other question I posted about an exercise revering to this theorem? :)

Comment: @Main I'll take a look later!